# AngularJS - grunt build blocked at htmlmin task

Tags: angularjs, build, gruntjs, yeoman-generator

I've made an AngularJS web application using Yeoman as project generator. When I run the command:

```
grunt build
```

all tasks start, but get stuck at the htmlmin task:

```
Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
```

and I need to do CTRL+Z.
Other tasks are done without problem (except some warnings in jshint).
However htmlmin task seems to be done when I look in HTML file in dist directory.
This problem came recentlty, in previous builds everything was OK.

What can cause htmlmin task issues?

Comment: this happened with me once , after debugging found that the issue was related to malformed HTML (my case that was a missing ending quotes in an attribute )

Comment: thanks, for the answer. I think you are right, but now the problem is how to find that malformed HTML. Do you have any ideas or suggest me some tools to find it? I'm trying with: xmllint --html fileName.html but no luck till now

Comment: You could use something like https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint or https://github.com/htmllint/htmllint

Comment: thanks for the help. I also found this that should be useful [link](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/issues/38) and as stated in mattrw89 post, looking in the html files I can found which is the last minified, so the first that is not minified is probably the one with some problem. As soon as I have time I'll take a look at that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of **Prayag Verma** I solved the issue. The problem was an attribute value not correctly put between "". To identify the file which had the error, I order the views folder (in dist project folder of Yeoman) alphabetically and I found the first HTML file that wasn't minified: that file, in the development section of my web app had the error.

Comment: Good idea to check the dist folder. I noticed that the broken file was the last one in the folder.